# Pandas_Python: how to check if a dataframe has changed

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a Pandas Dataframe that every hour reads data from a CSV file.
How can I play a sound when data in the dataframe changes (rows added) ??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `any(df_new != df_current) == True` would indicate a change or more succinct `df_new.equals(df_current)`

Comment: HI EdChum, thank you for your answer.
My question was more related to the logic of program flow.
How can I compare new and old dataframe dataframe without saving an intermediate csv ??

PROGRAM START

LOOP
READ CSV
CREATE NEW DF (ONLY THE FIRST TIME)
COMPARE UPDATED DF WITH OLD DF (every other time...)
IF NEW_DF != OLD_DF the play a sound...

I don't know If I've been clear :-) MY english is ugly :-)
Thank you in advance

Comment: Basically where you've defined compare updated df with old df would be where to do this, you could also do `df.equals(pd.read_csv(path_to_csv))` would also work so you wouldn't create a df unless the csv had changed

Comment: which OS are you using, where is the CSV located?

Comment: Thank you again Ed, your [df.equals(pd.read_csv(path_to_csv))] is very useful.
Elyase, I'm using Win 8. Csv in in a local folder.